# SqlException was unhandled by user code error, but information still being stored on database

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, sqlexception

So i'm using Visual Studio to create a asp.net web app in c# and I need some help regarding databases. I have a registration form that is filled out and depending on which radio button is selected, the information is stored in one of two tables. The issue I am having is when I hit the submit button on my app to store the data, it throws up an error message. The curious part is, the information still stores in the table even though I get the error message.

Can anyone help explain? I've attached pictures showing my code/error message and my tables. Thanks!

EDIT - This is my latest issue, posted from below:

**After tweaking with some stuff, I am not getting the error message anymore. Now, the parent radio button is working (storing the info in parent table), but the child radio button is not. (nothing is being sent to the children table.**

So after commenting out the 'if (parentRadBtn.Checked)' section so that the 'if (child.RadBtn.Checked)' section is first, information gets stored for children when running the app. So it seems there is an issue with my if statements and the program not reaching the 'if (child.RadBtn.Checked)' part. I have tried making it an 'if else' and various other things but none of them work. Can anyone spot what needs to be changed for the program to run through the children part? Thanks.

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akhzy.png)

[Code/error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dcmt.png)

```
**Updated code**

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Coursework
{
public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            successLabel.Text = ("Your submission is now being stored in our database");
        }
    }

    protected void parentRadBtn_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (parentRadBtn.Checked)
        {
            firstNameBox.Text = string.Empty;
            surnameBox.Text = string.Empty;
            dayDobList.Text = string.Empty;
            monthDobList.Text = string.Empty;
            yearDobList.Text = string.Empty;
            genderList.Text = string.Empty;
            postcodeBox.Text = string.Empty;
            teleBox.Text = string.Empty;
            emailBox.Text = string.Empty;
            userBox.Text = string.Empty;
            passwordBox.Text = string.Empty;

            genderList.Enabled = false;
            dayDobList.Enabled = false;
            monthDobList.Enabled = false;
            yearDobList.Enabled = false;

            surnameBox.Enabled = true;
            postcodeBox.Enabled = true;
            teleBox.Enabled = true;
            emailBox.Enabled = true;

            successLabel.Text = ("");
        }
    }

    protected void passwordBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void childRadBtn_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        else if (childRadBtn.Checked)
        {
            firstNameBox.Text = string.Empty;
            surnameBox.Text = string.Empty;
            dayDobList.Text = string.Empty;
            monthDobList.Text = string.Empty;
            yearDobList.Text = string.Empty;
            genderList.Text = string.Empty;
            postcodeBox.Text = string.Empty;
            teleBox.Text = string.Empty;
            emailBox.Text = string.Empty;
            userBox.Text = string.Empty;
            passwordBox.Text = string.Empty;

            genderList.Enabled = true;
            dayDobList.Enabled = true;
            monthDobList.Enabled = true;
            yearDobList.Enabled = true;

            surnameBox.Enabled = false;
            postcodeBox.Enabled = false;
            teleBox.Enabled = false;
            emailBox.Enabled = false;

            successLabel.Text = ("");
        }
    }

    protected void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=THEBEAST;Initial Catalog=newregDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        {
            if (parentRadBtn.Checked)
            {                  
                SqlCommand pa = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO parent(parentID, firstname, surname, postcode, telephone, email, password) VALUES (@parentID, @firstname, @surname, @postcode, @telephone, @email, @password)", connect);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parentID", userBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstNameBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", surnameBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", postcodeBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephone", teleBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordBox.Text);

                connect.Open();
                pa.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connect.Close();

                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                    userBox.Text = "";
                    firstNameBox.Text = "";
                    surnameBox.Text = "";
                    postcodeBox.Text = "";
                    teleBox.Text = "";
                    emailBox.Text = "";
                    passwordBox.Text = "";
                }
                else if (childRadBtn.Checked)
                {                     
                    SqlCommand ca = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO children(childID, firstname, dob, gender, password) VALUES (@childID, @firstname, @dob, @gender, @password)", connect);
                    ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@childID", userBox.Text);
                    ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstNameBox.Text);
                    ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dayDobList.Text + monthDobList.Text + yearDobList.Text);
                    ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", genderList.Text);                       
                    ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordBox.Text);

                    connect.Open();
                    ca.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connect.Close();

                    if (IsPostBack)
                    {
                        userBox.Text = "";
                        firstNameBox.Text = "";
                        dayDobList.Text = "";
                        monthDobList.Text = "";
                        yearDobList.Text = "";
                        genderList.Text = "";
                        passwordBox.Text = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The error is very clear. It says that  you are trying to insert a record that already exists in the table.

Comment: I know it seems clear but:

1. It isn't true, i'm entering completely different information every time I test.

2. The information still gets stored in the table.

Comment: The error is telling you that you are trying to insert a duplicate key into the table Children.   The record you are inserting already exists with that ID.

Comment: Again, like I said to William above, I am entering different information every time. I have the username set as the primary key as my coursework states that the username needs to be a unique ID, with no two being the same. I am extremely confused that the information still gets stored regardless of the error and that the error isn't true as i'm entering different information each time.

Comment: Also, looks like your code is inserting into both tables if you have parent option clicked.   So if you switch options and click button again you would get the duplicate key for the Child table

Comment: @ACostea Paste your code instead of using a picture.

Comment: How do you figure that it is inserting into both tables when parent radio button is clicked? I have two seperate if statements for if each radio button is checked and the SQL statement is insert into parent (when parent rad btn is checked) and insert in children (when children rad btn is checked).

Comment: Your condition `if(childRadBtn.Checked = true)` will always be `true` becaue you are assigning `true` with `=` instead of comparing with `==`.  Just do `if(childRadBtn.Checked)` instead.  In fact you have that issue with alot of your other `if` conditions.

Comment: Thank you juharr, I have corrected the if statements and removed the "= true". This has got rid of the error message when pressing the submit button. When the parent radio button is checked the information is stored correctly in the parent table but when the child radio button is selected the information isn't being sent to the children database. Any ideas why when looking at my code? Thanks

Comment: change your code to point to the same event handler so you write the code only once vs repeating the same code in 2 different events also create a case statement that will determine the sender of the radio button by name I would also create a method that would loop through the Controls using a lambda to set all of the textboxes Text to string.Empty vs having to write all of the textbox control names as well this could be cleaned up easily by 85% to be more readable as well as efficient in my opinion

Comment: This looks an awful lot like you're storing a password in plain-text. **DON'T DO THAT!!!**

Comment: Why is everything VARCHAR(50) in your database?  Surely Date of Birth should be a date, no?

Comment: Per your update: did you mean to check if the child radio button is checked as an "else if" to if(IsPostBack)?

Answer (score 0):

Step through your code checking the value of userBox.Text prior to executing the query. Column childID is the only one that can cause this error, and the database is reporting that it is 0 (or is that () meaning empty string?).

You can also try manually deleting the record each time you run your code - you should no longer get the error.

Additional changes you might want to consider:

1. Add a constraint disallowing empty string as a legal childID value;
2. Name all your constraints, including the primary key constraint (PK_children is more readable than what you are getting);

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I have added constraints so that something has to be entered into the primary key values, thank you :).

I mentioned above that after tweaking with some stuff, I am not getting the error message anymore. Now, the parent radio button is working (storing the info in parent table), but the child radio button is not. (nothing is being sent to the children table. Any ideas why? Thanks again.

Comment: As mentioned previously, several of your conditionals are actually assignments. (parentRadBtn.Checked = true) is wrong, should be (parentRadBtn.Checked == true). Assuming parent and child radios cannot be simultaneously checked, your logic should have the child radio button conditional as an else if rather than if.

Comment: Hey again :), someone else pointed that out, so I have included my updated code with the '= true' parts removed and the '(parentRadBtn.Checked)' statement made an else if rather than just an if. It still isn't storing data in the children table even after making these changes!