# if, else if statements not working properly

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
    protected void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=THEBEAST;Initial Catalog=newregDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        {
            if (parentRadBtn.Checked)
            {                  
                SqlCommand pa = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO parent(parentID, firstname, surname, postcode, telephone, email, password) VALUES (@parentID, @firstname, @surname, @postcode, @telephone, @email, @password)", connect);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parentID", userBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstNameBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", surnameBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", postcodeBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephone", teleBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordBox.Text);

                connect.Open();
                pa.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connect.Close();

                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                    userBox.Text = "";
                    firstNameBox.Text = "";
                    surnameBox.Text = "";
                    postcodeBox.Text = "";
                    teleBox.Text = "";
                    emailBox.Text = "";
                    passwordBox.Text = "";
                }
                else if (childRadBtn.Checked)
                {                     
                    SqlCommand ca = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO children(childID, firstname, dob, gender, password) VALUES (@childID, @firstname, @dob, @gender, @password)", connect);
                    ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@childID", userBox.Text);
                    ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstNameBox.Text);
                    ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dayDobList.Text + monthDobList.Text + yearDobList.Text);
                    ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", genderList.Text);                       
                    ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordBox.Text);

                    connect.Open();
                    ca.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connect.Close();

                    if (IsPostBack)
                    {
                        userBox.Text = "";
                        firstNameBox.Text = "";
                        dayDobList.Text = "";
                        monthDobList.Text = "";
                        yearDobList.Text = "";
                        genderList.Text = "";
                        passwordBox.Text = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hi all,

I've looked around at other questions but none of them match my exact problem or aren't in c#. I'm creating an asp.net web app in C# using Visual Studio. I have a page with a form to fill out for either a parent or a child (done using radio buttons). When I select the parent radio button and use the submit button to send information to the parent table in my database, it works fine. When trying to do the same with the child radio button, no information is stored in the child table in my database.

I commented out the if '(parentRadBtn.Checked)' statement and made the 'else if (childRadBtn.Checked)' a standalone if statement and it began working correctly (storing the information in the children table). This has led me to believe that the app isn't reaching the 'else if (childRadBtn.Checked)' statement and after a lot of messing around I can't get it to work. By looking at my code above, can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong with my if statements? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. I very much doubt that you need 142 lines to demonstrate this. I doubt that the database side is relevant either - reduce everything as far as you can.

Comment: "none of them match my exact problem or aren't in c#"  The trick is to *understand* those problems and their solutions, and apply that knowledge to your own problem.  You will rarely find an *exact* match of your problem.

Comment: I edited the code to show just the submit button click event as this is where my if statements are and where the issue lies, thanks for pointing that out Jon.

Comment: You should be referencing your related question [SqlException was unhandled by user code error, but information still being stored on database](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41043510/719186), but this question looks pretty close to a duplicate of that one.

Comment: FYI With an `else if` it means it only executes if the `if` and any `else if` that precede it were all `false`.  You have `if(IsPostBack)` before the `else if` and also inside of it where it will always be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your else if block for the Child button is inside the if block of the Parent button.

```
if (parentRadBtn.Checked)
    {                  
        ...
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
        ...
        }
        else if (childRadBtn.Checked)
        {  
            ...                   
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
            ...
            }
        }
    }
```

If parentRadBtn.Checked is false you'll never reach the else if (childRadBtn.Checked) block.

What you want is this:

```
if (parentRadBtn.Checked)
    {                  
        ...
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
        ...
        }
    }
    else if (childRadBtn.Checked)
    {  
        ...                   
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I was looking for. I knew it was just a case of adding or taking away a bracket but couldn't figure it out myself. Thank you again :)

Comment: I would put the `if (IsPostBack)` outside of the two if blocks.  Like this it won't work the way you expect.